# Max speed for wheel bearings

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, bearings, speed

I don't know much about bikes. I've got myself an older Specialized Stumpjumper. I asked myself the other day while I was riding with +50km/h through the forest what the maximum speed is the wheel bearings will endure and if there is e difference between smooth roads and trails.

Comment: You were going significantly faster than a Tour de France-level pro rider averages on a racing road bicycle?  But you were in a forest?  On an old mountain bike?  Ooooh-kay.

Comment: @AndrewHenle 50km/h is perfectly possible downhill on a fire road.  The limit is nerves  or maybe spinning out.  The OP didn't claim to be doing it on the flat

Comment: Related: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/68324/what-range-of-rotational-speed-for-bike-wheel-bearings

Comment: @AndrewHenle I was doing 50 km/h on a forest gravel downhill yesterday, what is so unbelievable about that?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Downhill on a fire road ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

50km/h = 13.9m/s = 833m/min. Wheel circumference is roughly 2m so that the wheel is spinning at 417rpm. Sealed industrial bearings easily withstand 10.000rpm and more. The steel ball bearings inside even more.

Comment: Thank you. So I will never reach the limit.

Comment: Not unless you travel at over 1,000km/h based on the above maths.

Comment: Your calculations look off, just roughly guessing to get near 833m/min you’d need to be doing close to 60mph. Did you forget the conversion between mph and kmh ?

Comment: Just for clarity I worked out the circumference of an average 700c / 29” tire to be 0.91m. Calculating 831.31m per minute / circumference = 912rpm

Comment: @DanK I always calculate in SI. Circumference for a 700c, 28mm tyre is 2105mm. A 26 MTB rim with a 1.50 tyre is 2010mm according to this table: https://bikelah.com/image/data/bicycle%20-%20cycle%20computer/cateye-wireless-cc-rd310w-tire-sizechart.jpg or google tire size chart.

Comment: @Carel I’m pretty sure that is looking at area rather than circumference. I used 29” x 3.141 (pi) /100 to calculate the circumference. A 700c tire wouldn’t measure over 2m if it was laid flat would it ?

Comment: @DanK: Take the measure! It isn't laid flat, it's inflated. I got 2.10m for a 25c on my bike, so that's pretty close! (had quoted 28mm but read the correct value for 25c, scusi!)

Comment: @dan k - I follow your reasoning until you divided by 100 to convert inches to meters. What’s the logic there? Should multiply by 2.54 to get to cm before you divide by 109. Also, to get a more precise diameter (and already in cm) add 2x the tire size to 622 for a 29er or 700 wheel